# How to formulate non smooth function with an if statement as a linear program?

Tags: linear-programming

$f(a) = \begin{cases}
a &  a \ge 1 \\
2a-1 & a\lt 1
\end{cases}$

$\text{minimize } f(u_1) + f(u_2)$

$\begin{align*}
\text{s.t. } &\text{some constraints involving } u_1, u_2\\
& \text{some constraints involving } f(u_1), f(u_2)
\end{align*}$

I know that you can formulate non-smooth functions such as max, min, absolute value as LP. Is it possible to express if statement as LP?

If so, you can provide an example on how to do so

Note: If you can provide a link to a textbook that describe this in depth, it would be appreciated too

Comment: you minimize a concave function which cannot be expressed with linear constraints; you'll have to introduce binary variables

Comment: @LinAlg Can you explain how this would work?

Comment: see Chapter 7.6 of https://aimms.com/english/developers/resources/manuals/optimization-modeling/